# How to pass data from a controller action to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 5 app, in the Home controller's Index() action I'm reading a value from a Web.config variable:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var environment = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
...
}
```

I need to pass that value onto a JavaScript function, which runs when Home/Index.cshtml is rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if environment == "External" - pseudo code
    $("#AccessInstanceListItem").hide();
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

P.S. Ideally, I would like to pass this value to a script, which runs when_layout.cshtml is rendered, but I do not have any controllers associated with the layout view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewBag fetaure in MVC.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           ViewBag.environment  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"];
...
}
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if environment == '@ViewBag.environment' - pseudo code
    $("#AccessInstanceListItem").hide();
});
```

refer other info from below link.

[viewbag in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905193/using-viewbag-with-jquery-asp-net-mvc-3)

refer Darin answer.